# openvpn client connection is not establishing

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

What does this error means? My client.conf file works in other clients like ubuntu. But in centos 5.7 client it is giving this error;

```
Thu Mar 22 23:20:49 2012 us=231847 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to xx.xx.xx.xx:1194: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
```

Comment: Is there selinux enabled or any firewall ??

Comment: SELINUX=disabled and I removed iptables

Comment: pasting logs from server would be helpful because now it's hard to tell what is wrong... but im considering that server has problem with comunicating with client

Comment: Nothing happens on server side from this client

Comment: can you ping server from client ?

Comment: No, but it can resolve the ip. I think pinging is not allowed on this university network.

Comment: resolving ip doest tell you that u can connect to server ..  hmm maybe try telnet ip.ip.ip.ip 1194

Comment: can you connect to the vpn server locally, e.g. run the client on the same machine the server is on, and connect...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the packet is being rejected, either by a local firewall or a firewall which responds with an ICMP Destination Unreachable message. Try sending a UDP packet to your VPN server on port 1194 with something like `nc -v -u vpn.example.com 1194`, or run `tcpdump` to see what response is being received.

Comment: Thanks. I can see all the traffic and I can check which ports that it can connect.